# Retrieve all selected items checkcombbox c#

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C#, I have a `CheckComboBox`, when I select several items and convert to a list and run a Linq query and bind to a Datagrid only first item is retrieve and others not retrieve please help me.

```
string find = checkcombobox1.SelectedText;
string[] stringList = find.Split(",".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

List<string> openItems = new List<string>();    
foreach (var item in stringList)
{
    openItems.Add(item);
}

var q1 = db1.appearance1s.Where(c=>openItems.Contains(c.buy_from)).Select(x => x).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = q1;
```

Comment: can you post the error you are facing

Answer (score 0):

If checkcombobox1 is a checked list box, you can query the CheckedItems property for the value.  In this example, resultItems will contain a list of string values that you can bind to your control.

```
var resultItems = checkcombobox1.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().Where(x => x.Contains(buy_from)).ToList();
```